# what does set -g means in config files?

Tags: shell-script, configuration, tmux, set

In one of my config **[~/.tmux.conf]** there is a line :

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -s escape-time 10
```

I think it sets global variables of my system. But I am not sure.. I searched for it on the web ... 
& even the man pages doesn't give me information about -g option
when in **bash** I did **help set**
and there are not information about -g option and -s option..

How do I find out what these command does by reading man pages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set` is an alias to `tmux` `set-option`

[tmux man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux)

Commands which set options are as follows:

**set-option [-agsuw] [-t target-session | target-window] option value**

**(alias: set)** Set a window option with -w (equivalent to the set-window-option command), a server option with -s, otherwise a session option.

If **-g** is specified, the global session or window option is set. With -a, and if the option expects a string, value is appended to the existing setting. The -u flag unsets an option, so a session inherits the option from the global options. It is not possible to unset a global option.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bash conf, it's tmux confs, so you should look for information about this option in tmux help.

Quick searching gave me that:

> If -g is used, the change is made in the global environment;
>   otherwise, it is applied to the session environment for
>   target-session.

Answer (score 1):

Those are `tmux` commands. The `tmux` config file is read and interpreted by `tmux`.  The shell language does not apply.

You're looking for the `tmux` man page, which  describes the `-s` and `-g` flags as well as the meaning of the options (as they are referred in the `tmux` man page) such as `default-terminal` and `escape-time`.

**Note that the `set` command does not appear to be documented on the man page on GNU/Linux, but it is an alias of `set-option`.**